# How to remove columns in Wordpress backend

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, backend

My title is pretty general I know that but I hope to explain in more detail here.

In the default wordpress backend users who have the right permissions can manage comments on their own posts. In the overview of this page there you see in this case some detailed data from the comment author, that is his name and his e-mailaddress. Is there a way to remove them in a decent way as in not hacking the Wordpress core.

Kind regards,

Pim

Comment: Please try to improve your question; with specifics for a most accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a reputable '*Admin User Role Management*' plugin. Based on your needs.

**Example 1:**

Adminimize *(Personal Recommendation)*

https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/screenshots/

**Example 2:**

User Role Editor

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/

If you want to **customize manually with hard-code; reference the codex** docs on how to do so.

*ie:*

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role
https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities